# Is there a formula in google sheets where it picks one option out of many to assign to a cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column full of models of cars, a column next to it that assigns the correct car type (hatchback, pick up, etc) to the car model.

In the third column, I have more than 1000 car models which need to have these car types associated with them.
Is there a formula that can help me do this?
I tried nested Ifs but there are around 45 car models so this is a bit inefficient I thought.

Comment: share a copy of your spreadsheet pls

Comment: Vlookup, Index/Match, Filter, Query all of these function will help you.

Comment: One way is to use dropdowns ie data validation but you would need to make a list of models per manufacturer or a logic table.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `iF` you can use `VLOOKUP`.